# Add a new notification when push notification receives and replace old one

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, push-notification, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am using push notification on my app. I used to display a notification when a push notification comes.if I send another notification (without clearing the previous notification)it replaces the new notification .Please give me solution very quickly its very necessary to me.
 And this is my code

```html
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
  function sendNotification($token,$message){
   $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
   $msg = array
          (
  'body'  => 'T...thoihgcggc',
  'title' => 'Dexter Studio 123',
  'subtitle'=> 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
         'tickerText'=> 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
        'vibrate'=>1,
         'sound'=>'default',
         'tag'=>'hellesjhasvhd',
         'badge'=>0,
         'ID'=>12,
              
          );
   $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $token, // HERE IT IS
            'data' => $msg
        );
   
   define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "Apikey"); 
   $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key='. GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
   //print_r($headers);

   $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
  $result = curl_exec($ch );
  echo $result;
  curl_close( $ch );
  }

 
  $conn = mysqli_connect("hostname","usrname","password","db");
  $query = "SELECT * from tbltoken";
  $token = array();
  $results = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($results)>0 ){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
     $token[] = $row["Token"]; 
    }
   }
   //print_r($token);

 mysqli_close($conn); 

 $message = array("message" => "FCM push notification" );
 $message_status = sendNotification($token,$message);
 echo $message_status;
```

Comment: Please solve my problem , I stuck in a case